# creating empty nodes with boundaries in gamescene.sks

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm looking at the adventure project by apple to learn how they created the world and other things in the game.

looking at the AdventureWorld.sks file, I see they have a bunch of different "wall" nodes  that are placed on top of where the walls are in the image of the background. However, I don't understand how they have created the green rectangles for the empty wall nodes.

I'm adding a new "empty node" to the scene, but how do I create the rectangular shape around the empty node? Also, is this the physics body of the node?

heres what it looks like: http://duxfox.deviantart.com/art/stuff-508377009?ga_submit_new=10%253A1421764250

notice theres a node called "wall" that doesn't have the green rectangle physics body, how do I add this inside an sks file? the other nodes have it somehow

Comment: Yes, this is the node's physics body being drawn.

Comment: any idea on how to replicate this? It looks like they did this inside the scene.sks file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a solid colored SKSpriteNode with

```
let node = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.greenColor(), size: CGSizeMake(100,100))
```

Another method is to use `SKShapeNode` which lets you draw any shape, but note, that it is known to cause memory leaks.

Another option is to create an `UIImage` with the content you want and make a `SKTexture` out of it, which you then assign to a `SKSpriteNode`.

Comment: hey, thanks for the answer. I know about the spritenodes and shapenodes, but they seem to be using just a plain SKNode

Comment: A `SKNode` has no size and no texture or the like attached. Therefore I think it is rather unlikely. Are you sure that this is its real datatype? Maybe it just is the base class you are seeing (which would make sense).

Comment: I'm pretty sure its an SKNode, thats why I'm confused

Comment: No, can't be: "The SKNode class doesn’t draw any visual content. [...] All visual elements in a Sprite Kit-based game are drawn using predefined SKNode subclasses.", see [SKNode Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKNode/frame). It could be, that it contains several other nodes as childs.

Comment: I think it might be showing the physics body for the node.. can they have a physics body? I'll try to post a picture somewhere and link it in the question

Comment: Yes, they do have a `physicsBody` property. It could be the case that you are seeing this, yes (light green colored rectangle).

Comment: so how do you create that inside an sks file? Or is this created in code? I know how to do it in code, but they seem to be generating it inside the sks file- see the updated question for image also

Comment: No, this is not a `physicsBody`, it seems like a `SKShapeNode`.

Comment: you can see the link again, I updated the image, the side options have the same options as an sknode, shape nodes have color/size options, also it says "node" at the top

Comment: Then, I have no idea.

Comment: no you have to help me, you don't understand, THE FATE OF THE WORLD DEPENDS! just kidding, thanks for trying : )

Answer (score 1):

The box corresponds to that of non-dynamic physics body. this option is available in the "colour sprite" object's sknode inspector under "physics definition". dynamic bodies are blue, none dynamic bodies are green(different when highlighted). However as I understand, it is not available in the "empty node".

I don't see any extra nodes in the .sks file that would correspond to the expected colornodes so I have no idea apple how managed to do what they did unless they had options that we somehow didn't. A note: The color nodes do not have a name that appears in the view for the .sks. look at the picture and you will see despite having a name in the inspector, the node does not have a name

I hope this helps. If you were able to figure it out. I would like to know

[image: example of colorsprite as physics body, while set on transparent and the physics definition]

Answer (score 0):

I have the same question, and when I was searching the answer, I found when you choose the assistant editor of the sks file, you can find a lot of empty file, choose any one will cause xcode quit.